# how to know which version of jar is my tomcat server using

Tags: api, tomcat, jar, loader, overwrite

Why I need to do this:  In my application I have some JAR file for connecting to MYSQL DB, now I have to extend this API so that my application can communicate to MongoDB.To do this I have to make changes in existing JAR file.

I don't have the source code of the JAR files so I de-compiled it, used the code to implement the interfaces, now I am unable to make a JAR file because may be the de-compiler did not de-compile the classes properly in the first place.  So I separately compiled the newly written classes, I want some of the new classes to overwrite the existing ones.
I know that tomcat looks for classes in the following order:
1. System class loader classes
2. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
3. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
so I put new classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ directory.
My tomcat server is still not using the newly added classes, is there any way to know which class is my class loader using and how to make it load the newly added classes?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Can you paste your code?

Comment: @JigneshDhua: I have an API with compliled classes (source is not available) I have to make some changes in the API i.e. I have to extend existing interfaces and write some classes. There are lots of classes in there so can not paste the code.